# Ban by Admod, looking for replacement, any idea?

Tags: iphone, ads

Is there any replacement for Admob? Iad network seem like not support singapore yet. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try [graystripe](http://www.greystripe.com/)
no idea if they work in singapore.